# Why can't I drag my formula down-giving an "inconsistent formula" error

Tags: excel

I am not able to drag my formula down the column as I usually would.  If I change the cell below the first one in the column to reference A6, it gives me an inconsistent formula error, and when I copy everything down it just repeats referencing A5 and A6 instead of

```
TEXT('[PV by Contract 09.30.2022.xlsx]PV by Contract'!$A$5,"00000")
```

Comment: Remove dollar sign from Infront of `5`. Try `=TEXT('[PV by Contract 09.30.2022.xlsx]PV by Contract'!$A5,"00000")` then drag down.

Comment: "Inconsistent formula" is a warning, not an error. If the formula does what you're expecting you're at liberty to ignore it (although it sounds like that isn't the case here).